# Index return multiple duplicate data

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhJ5a.png)I am trying to create a timesheet to return attendance for a specific program. I want to return the name all particpants who attended just the construction alone for different days from another sheet.

I used this formula =INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$B13:$B, MATCH('Form Responses 1'!$M$5, 'Form Responses 1'!$C14:$C, 0))

But if keeps returning multiple wrong names and duplicates. Can someone please share what I am doing wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRG47.png)

Comment: INDEX-MATCH and any lookup function are used to return only one value. If you want to return all the values use FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

You have a form where timesheets are submitted. You want to extract the details for employees attending only "Construction".

A `QUERY` is a good approach:

- Total Hours spent = "End Time":(hours*60)+minutes less "Start Time":(hours*60)+minutes

---

Enter this in Cell A1 of a blank sheet; assuming that the raw data is on `Form Responses 1`

```
=query({'Form Responses 1'!A1:I},"select Col1,Col2,Col9, Col4, Col5, 
  ((hour(Col5)*60)+minute(Col5)-(hour(Col4)*60)-minute(Col4))/60 
  where Col1 is not null and Col3 = 'Construction' 
  label Col1 'Date',Col4 'Start Time', Col5 'End Time',
  ((hour(Col5)*60)+minute(Col5)-(hour(Col4)*60)-minute(Col4))/60 'Total Hours Spent'")
```

In this example, I have returned just the `minutes`; but this can be converted to hours:minutes, or other values.

---

**SAMPLE RESULT**

[image: sample]